# QTcpsocket/QTcpserver transmission, how to use QdataStream to transfer a table data

Tags: python, qtcpsocket, qdatastream

QTcpsocket/QTcpserver transmission, how to use QdataStream to transfer a table data??

There are ideas: Write data stream on each row and then call write(), but how to write again?

Existing issues: Data is garbled, the first line of data is written repeatedly..

Extract saved data stream data from fh file, write self.block for TCP transfer
(The data is saved in the format of each row of the table, the number of rows and list data is read out) ->Cannot be displayed properly
Seeking examples or ideas, written in PYQT5

Server code:

```
self.block = QByteArray()
fh = QFile(name)
        fh.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        tableData = QDataStream(fh)        # Get Data from File
        tableData.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_5_6)

        stream = QDataStream(self.block, QIODevice.WriteOnly)    # Input data to socket
        stream.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_5_6)    
        self.clientConnection = self.server.nextPendingConnection()    


        while not tableData.atEnd():
            num,table=0,''
            num = tableData.readUInt16()
            table = tableData.readQStringList()

            stream.writeUInt16(0)
            stream.writeUInt16(num)
            stream.writeQStringList(table)
            stream.device().seek(0)
            stream.writeUInt16(self.block.size() - SIZEOF_INT16)  #
            self.clientConnection.write(self.block)
            self.clientConnection.flush()
```

client.py

```
def readMessage(self):
    try:

        print('readmessage')

        stream = QDataStream(self.socket)
        stream.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_5_6)
        while not stream.atEnd():

            if self.blockSize == 0:

                if self.socket.bytesAvailable()<SIZEOF_UINT16:

                    return
                self.blockSize = stream.readUInt16()

            if self.socket.bytesAvailable()<self.blockSize:

                return
            num=stream.readUInt16()
            message = stream.readQStringList()      #?????????

            print(num,message)
            if num<1:

                self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1) # First row Data
                for a in range(0, 11):
                    # print(a)
                    newItem = QTableWidgetItem(message[a])
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(0, a, newItem)
            else:
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(0)
                for a in range(0, 11):                      
                    newItem = QTableWidgetItem(message[a])
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(0, a, newItem)
        print('closee')
        self.socket.disconnect()
        self.socket.close()

    except:
        self.socket.close()
```

The input Data:

[image]

The error output data:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of your data, paste it into your answer so people don't have to follow an external link to see it, and so they can copy and paste it when trying to replicate your issues if need be.

Comment: What is your entry, a .txt file? if so, you could share the file.

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: file.dat (it is empty file) i have built a tableWidget for fill in the table data. The file is save by QdataStream. Save and open all by QdataStream.

Comment: It is python 3, and use pyqt5